# How To Set Appsettings.Json Readonly On .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have a project template on visual studio for .net core 3.1 and I want to set appsettings.json and appsettings.Development readonly, appsettings.local read/write for developers.

Is it possible to to?

Answer (score 1):

You could open the project root folder via File Explorer, then set the `appsettings.json` file `Read-only`, then when you update the file content programmatically, it will show an exception to prevent update.

[image]

**Note**

By using the above method, when you update the appsettings.json file via visual studio, it will show this prompt:

[image]

If you choose the "Overwride" button, you have to re-set the `appsettings.json` file `Read-only`.

Besides, when using `System.IO.File` class to write the value in the `appsettings.json` file, it will throw an exception (because the file is read-only). So, you have to use the `Try-Catch` statement to catch the exception.